# Can I drywall directly over cinder block (ceiling) using 7/8" hat channel?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, cinderblock

We live in a condo that was previously a Hospital.  In the early 1980s they installed the drywall ceilings using metal track.  We removed the drywall and track to raise the ceiling from 8' to 11'.  The ceiling is now cinder block under concrete.
Can we install drywall directly over cinder block using 7/8" metal hat channel as our "furring strips?"
I have plenty of 7/8" hat channel available from removing old track lighting.  Hat channel would be attached using tapcon  concrete screws.  Would use drywall screws and adhesive to attach to hat channel.

Comment: How does one apply "cinder block" to a ceiling?

Comment: Like this? http://usccllc.com/DubaiMarriott2.jpg

Comment: @isherwood, Man there's something not-right about that...

Answer (score 1):

the hat channel should make a nice support for the sheetrock. dosent leave much room for electricial unless you have surface mount boxes (for lighting).

Comment: Yeah, I'd think Allen would have done better to keep the track and raise the ceiling from 8' to 10'6 (leaving some room to work in), but presumably way too late for that now unless changing gears to acoustic tile or something.

Answer (score 1):

yes, that would be the best plan to install drywall over concrete or block. Drywall should be installed on a level and flat surface. If the surface is  irregular installing furring strips that the drywall can be fastened to will produce the best results. It wouldn't be a bad idea to apply adhesive to the drywall/furring strips for added strength. Consider 3/8 inch thick drywall for an easier positioning on the 11 foot ceiling. Now is the time to install any sound-proofing and/or insulation (i.e. board insulation).